# Pull changes from heroku app running wordpress

Tags: wordpress, git, heroku

I'm wondering how to pull (or fetch) all the changes that I made on a wordpress installation running on heroku.

Example:

I have a plugin that let me upload an avatar of me on the server (avoiding gravatar). Okay, the avatar is ready and uploaded on the server (in this case, the heroku instance). So, when I do a pull or a fetch to get that change (the image) on my local files, I get nothing else than "Already updated".

I do:

```
git pull heroku master
```

And nothing is actually added or changed on the local files. Instead, I get:

```
From: heroku.com:app-123-456
* branch               master      -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

So the image I've just upload is not in my local files, but yes in the remote files.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Changes made to the dyno filesystem that your app is running on will not be reflected in the git repository associated with your app. Also, the dyno filesystem is ephemeral and changes are lost across deploys and when dynos are recycled (which happens at least daily).

Instead of relying on the dyno filesystem for persistence, you should make sure files are persisted to S3 or similar services.

This custom Wordpress build pack should be a good start: https://github.com/mchung/heroku-buildpack-wordpress